# How to manage the backup of users if i have to reinstall windows?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-backup

I have a computer with windows with two partitions. One for the system and another with a folder "Data", that has many subfolders and files, and I have about 10 users that has different permissions in this subfolders.

I could make a backup of the system partition and I could make another backup for the partition with the data.

If windows fails, I could restore the backup of the system, but supose that for some reason I can't restore, because it is another different computer or I want to update the windows version or for some another reason.

If I create users with the same name and password, really for windows they are different users that the users that have permissions in the data folders, because windows assign different ID for this users.

So I was wondering how to do in this case, if it is possible to backup the windows users and restore in a fresh windows installation.

Also I am opened to know good practice in backup strategies for this structure, a partition for the system and a partition for the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system generates a Security identifier (SID) that uniquely
identifies a particular account or group, at the time the account or group
is created.
No two accounts or groups on the computer ever share the same SID.
The SID is unique for the computer where it was created.
Even for a domain containing multiple computers, each SID is unique within
the entire domain.

This means that there is no way for you to transfer SIDs between Windows
installations. If the new computer contains its own Windows installation,
the SIDs from the old computer are unusable in it.

The only solution for preserving the data and permissions of a disk that
is partitioned in two is to take a backup image of the entire disk.

This image can be restored into the new computer, using a product that
can restore to a disk with a different size. The restored
old Windows version can then be updated, or upgraded,
or missing drivers installed on the new computer.

There are several backup product that can do the above. For recovering
from a catastrophic failure, choose one that has a boot media.
My favorite is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Reference : Microsoft's
[Security identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers).

Comment: So if I want to install a new version of operative system, will I need to create the users again and set the permissions to the folder manually?

Comment: Yes. To avoid this problem, you need to copy Windows and disk as-is.